# Изменение размера значка звука (вставленного файла) в MSWord

Tags: delphi, visual-basic

Я формирую MSWord’овский документ, и туда из БД вставляю звуковые файлы.

```
var
  LClassType, LFileName, LLinkToFile, LDisplaySaIcon, LIconFileName, LIconIndex, LIconLabel, LRange: Olevariant;
begin
…
  LClassType := 'Package';
  LFileName := PrPathForVoice+ibqEmpty.FieldByName('EW1').AsString+'.mp3';
  LLinkToFile := false;
  LDisplaySaIcon := false;
  WordApplication1.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(LClassType, LFileName, LLinkToFile, LDisplaySaIcon,
                                                       EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
…
end;
```

В Word они выглядят как значки (ярлыки), определенного размера.
**Я хочу уменьшить размеры этих значков**.
Я бы посмотрел это в самом макросе, но все дело в том, что во время записи макроса, изменить размеры не получается. Можно менять только после окончания записи макроса.
Хотя последним параметром функции "AddOLEObject" я вляется "LRange" - но по-моему немного не совсем то, [учитывая](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835835(v=office.15).aspx).
Макрос в *MSWord* выглядит вот так:

```
Set y = Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType:="Package", FileName:= _
    "D:\Prog\Eng_gdb\Documents\Voice\accept.mp3", LinkToFile:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False)
  y.Height = 20
  y.Width = 20
```

Но если перевести в Delphi, то:

```
WordApplication1.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(LClassType, LFileName, LLinkToFile, LDisplaySaIcon, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam).Height := 20;
WordApplication1.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(LClassType, LFileName, LLinkToFile, LDisplaySaIcon, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam).Width := 20;
```

Но так добавляется два объекта с разной высотой и шириной.
Мне каким-то образом нужно присвоить объекту размеры до вставки?

Comment: На полноценный ответ не тянет, но:

не совсем правильный перевод в Delphi.
Должно быть так: 
obj:=WordApp1.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOleObject();

obj.Height:=20;

obj.Width:=20;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
var
  MyOLEObject: T{что_там_возвращает_AddOLEObject};
...
MyOLEObject := WordApplication1.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(LClassType, LFileName, LLinkToFile, LDisplaySaIcon, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
MyOLEObject.Height := 20;
MyOLEObject.Width := 20;
```

Comment: AddOleObject, как и все остальные методы работы с объектами MS Office, возвращает OLEVariant

Comment: А скажите, как так получается: строка  >> WordApplication1.Selection...  - непосредственно выводит данные в "*.doc".   И потом же эта функция возвращает значение переменной, которая уже меняет размеры. Т.е. Уже после вывода объекта??? ("лошадь сзади телеги" - получается?)

Comment: Лошадь не сзади :) До того, как вставлен объект, для word его не существует. Чтобы поменять свойства чего-либо, нужно чтобы это что-либо появилось. AddOleObject "появляет" новый объект в документе и возвращает его для возможности изменения. Для примера - вы же не можете поменять размеры у TForm до того, как создадите ее?

Comment: Я думаю, что таким образом обходятся какие-то ограничения в MS Office. Опять по аналогии с Delphi - если мы создадим контрол без привязки его к форме (Parent = nil & Owner = nil), то при попытке что-либо с ним сделать вполне можем получить exception `Control has no parent window`, т.к. он пытается перерисоваться, а рисовать-то не на чем...

Comment: конечно вопросов нет, что свойства меняются после создания объекта. Но как то мне казалось, что где-то надо вроде так 1) MyOLEObject := InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(... - создали объект, 2) MyOLEObject.Height .... t.Width := 20; - применили к нему значения, 3) WordApplication1.Selection... - вывели его (синтаксис конечно отдыхает, но ход событий где-то такой)

Comment: Спасибо за подробные разъяснения **Kami** :)

Comment: @kami Не обязательно `OLEVariant `, там может быть и какой-нибудь интерфейс.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci ну, насколько я помню, все объекты, с которыми работаем в MSOffice - это COM-объекты, естественным образом реализующие IDispatch, что отлично укладывается в OLEVariant.